# Is it possible to pass Parcelable object via Navigation component deeplink?

Tags: android, android-navigation-graph

I use navigation component and use deep link for passing the value or changing page I can pass primitive and enum objects I never try passing Parcelable object via deep link is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think for now it's impossible, because our data only can be received from the URI.

Just like [documentation at Google](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link) said, it only show how to pass data with native value.

And with deeplink, we can access our data from Browser, so if we access from browser, of course we can't make object data right?